# Xml file with C# can't get the value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<Vitals>
<Vendor>General Electric Healthcare</Vendor>
<Model>Pro/Procare</Model>
    <Result name="Mean_arterial_pressure">
        <Value>86</Value>
        <Units name="mmHg"></Units>
        <Time_stamp year="2008" month="11" day="18" hour="12" minute="33" second="14"></Time_stamp>
    </Result>
    <Result name="Systolic_blood_pressure">
        <Value>130</Value>
        <Units name="mmHg"></Units>
        <Time_stamp year="2008" month="11" day="18" hour="12" minute="33" second="14"></Time_stamp>
    </Result>
    <Result name="Diastolic_blood_pressure">
        <Value>67</Value>
        <Units name="mmHg"></Units>
        <Time_stamp year="2008" month="11" day="18" hour="12" minute="33" second="14"></Time_stamp>
    </Result>
    <Result name="Pulse">
        <Value>73</Value>
        <Units name="BPM"></Units>
        <Method>blood_pressure</Method>
        <Time_stamp year="2008" month="11" day="18" hour="12" minute="33" second="14"></Time_stamp>
  </Result>
</Vitals>
```

and Here is my sourcecode, I having the issue how to get the result name and the value?

```
private void btnReadXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("C:\\dinamap.xml");


    XmlNodeList doc_results = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Vitals/Vendor/Model/Result[@name='Systolic_blood_pressure']");
    foreach (XmlNode pnode in doc_results)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode cnode in pnode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (cnode.Name == "Value")
            {
                h.Add(pnode.Attributes["name"].InnerText + cnode.Name, cnode.Attributes["name"].InnerText);
            }
            else
            {
                h.Add(pnode.Attributes["name"].InnerText + "_" + cnode.Name, cnode.InnerText);
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

May I know what wrong of my code? always can't get the value.
I need to get the value from xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be easier if you used LINQ to XML for this.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path/to/xml");

var results =
    from result in doc.Descendants("Result")
    select new
    {
        Name = (string) result.Attribute("name"),
        Value = (string) result.Element("Value"),
        Units = (string) result.Element("Units").Attribute("name")
    };
```

You could then filter by Name if you needed:

```
var sysBp = results.Single(x => x.Name == "Systolic_blood_pressure");
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iZ4a24) for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

On line 5, your xPath specify `Model` is a child of `Vendor` while `Vendor` contains only a string (`<Vendor>General Electric Healthcare</Vendor>`).

Moreover, to navigate with xPath i advice you to use `SelectNodes` function.

Try this instead :

```
XmlNodeList doc_results = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Vitals/Model/Result[@name='Systolic_blood_pressure']");
```

Comment: if at the same time I need show all the @name ="Systolic_blood_pressure", "Diastolic_blood_pressure" ,name="Diastolic_blood_pressure" &" Pulse", together with he <Value> ?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently trying to retrieve the "name" [`attribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx) of the child node, which it does not actually have in the case of your value node. If you use [`cnode.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value(v=vs.110).aspx) you can get the contents of a text note.

Also, `Result` is *not* a child of `Model`, which is *not* a child of `Vendor`. You'll either want to properly make them children or change the path you're setting for `doc_results`

Answer (score 0):

```html
private void btnReadXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\dinamap.xml");

            var results = from result in doc.Descendants("Result")
                          select new
                          {
                              Name = (string)result.Attribute("name"),
                              Value = (string)result.Element("Value"),
                              Units = (string)result.Element("Units").Attribute("name")
                          };

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("{result.Name}: {result.Value} {result.Units}");

            }
         
        }
```